# Можно ли использовать 1 файл из MIT репозитория без указания лицензии?

Tags: github, лицензирование

Есть проект на гитхаб с MIT лицензией. Могу ли я скачать 1 файл оттуда и использовать его без указания лицензии? Если нет, то где мне её надо указывать? Добавлять дополнительный файл лицензии рядом с этим файлом?

Comment: Нельзя. Если вы планируете просто взять файл как есть (а не копировать куски из него в свои файлы и т.п.), то можно воткнуть текст лицензии в начало этого файла в комментарии

Comment: В самоход ходить можно, попадаться нельзя

Answer (score 1):

Лучше в заголовке файла в виде комментария разместить саму лицензию или ссылку на её текст и добавить авторов. Вот [пример](https://github.com/go-gitea/gitea/blob/main/services/agit/agit.go) или [вот](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/console/bridge.go)